# tree command on osx bash

Tags: ruby, bash, unix, tree, pry

I'm following a [screen cast](http://vimeo.com/26391171) on a ruby gem called [pry](http://pry.github.com/). At 8:10, the .tree command is used, which I believe is a Unix command.

It does not appear to be working on my system:

```
[24] pry(main)> .tree
\Error: there was a problem executing system command: tree
```

and I have traced the issue to [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/pry/pry/master/Pry/DefaultCommands), in which pry references a shell command:

```
Pry::CommandSet.new do

  command(/\.(.*)/, "All text following a '.' is forwarded to the shell.", :listing => ".<shell command>") do |cmd|
    if cmd =~ /^cd\s+(.+)/i
      dest = $1
      begin
        Dir.chdir File.expand_path(dest)
      rescue Errno::ENOENT
        output.puts "No such directory: #{dest}"
      end

    else
      if !system(cmd)
        output.puts "Error: there was a problem executing system command: #{cmd}"
      end
    end
  end
```

from the context of bash I tried using the command tree with no luck:

```
projects/sms(apps2)$ tree
-bash: tree: command not found
~/projects/sms(apps2)$ .tree
-bash: .tree: command not found
```

This looks incredibly useful, how can I get this command?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**Using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):**

`brew install tree`

**Using [macports](https://www.macports.org/):**

`sudo port install tree`

**Using [the source](https://web.archive.org/web/20210727130725/http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/):**

[Follow these directions.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130527203022/http://shaunchapman.me/post/329270449/how-to-install-the-tree-command-on-mac-os-x) (Caveat; you should use the flags/etc. that make sense.)

<sup><rant>All systems should come with `tree`; I use it a lot. And we can post directory structures as text, not pics.</rant></sup>

Comment: it does not work for me, what' wrong with that? 
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7

Comment: $ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7
$ chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7
$ brew install tree

it's OK now, thx!

Answer (score 10):

For a simple approach you can also add the following `tree` alias to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file:

```
alias tree="find . -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'"
```

After editing the file, the command will be loaded when you restart your terminal, or you can load the command in your existing terminal by sourcing the config file using `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`.

This results in the following:

```
$ tree
.
|____.git
| |____config
| |____objects
| | |____pack
| | |____info
| |____HEAD
| |____info
| | |____exclude
| |____description
| |____hooks
| | |____commit-msg.sample
| | |____pre-rebase.sample
| | |____pre-commit.sample
| | |____applypatch-msg.sample
| | |____pre-receive.sample
| | |____prepare-commit-msg.sample
| | |____post-update.sample
| | |____pre-applypatch.sample
| | |____pre-push.sample
| | |____update.sample
| |____refs
| | |____heads
| | |____tags
```

Found this solution here:

- http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/09/view-folder-tree-terminal-mac-os-tree-equivalent/

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` file before running tree. might help those who don't know or want to restart the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Use `brew install tree` command on the terminal if you're using Homebrew on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same, but gives you a list of all directories and files in those directories using:

```
find .
```

You can also specify list directories only

```
find -type d
```

or if you want to see files only

```
find -type f
```

you can also specify depth

```
find -type d -maxdepth 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your shell startup file(`~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`):

```
tree() {
    find $1 -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
}
```

---

After restarting your shell, you can use the tree command like so:

```
% tree Downloads
Downloads
|____ideaIU-2020.1.3-no-jbr.tar.gz
|____Firicico.ttf
```